# Cannot Start Application Object Server after change database connection in AXAPTA 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I already create new database for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R2 (MicrosoftDynamicAX, MicrosoftDynamicAX_Model & MicrosoftDynamicBaseline).

All process has been finished and successfull, and then I try to change database connection in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Microsoft Dynamic AX Server Configuration. Please refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

And then I click Apply > OK.

After That, I tried to update the SID in table [dbo].[USERINFO] of MicrosoftDynamicAX database, but I cannot see all tables inside of this database, please refer to this following screenshot:

[image]

However, when I'm installing new database I didn't get any error at all.
Because of this condition, I cannot start the AOS for this database connection.

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider moving your question to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/tags/dynamics-ax-2012/info) because it is not programming related. Also provide more details on how you created the new databases.

Comment: @FH-Inway it's a fuzzy area with AX, as AX itself in all versions up to 2012 is also the development tool, and that makes it welcome here

Comment: @AnthonyBlake But the question is not about the development workspace, but seems to be a configuration/installation/setup issue.

Comment: @FH-Inway its AX, the application is required, the development workspace isn't stand alone. Hence why it's a fuzzy area here.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables/stored procedures/etc aren't there, that's a major problem and the setup did not complete correctly.

Do you have appropriate security to install everything? Check the event viewer and log files located in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Dynamics AX\Dynamics AX Setup Logs`